# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' & 'AS' & 'ORDER'

Tags: sql-server

I am using microsoft visual studio 2017 and sql server 2017.
when I run this statement in visual studio I don't get any error  :

```
@"
DECLARE @items table (item_id int, item_count int, item_type smallint)

INSERT INTO @items (item_id, item_count, item_type)
SELECT TOP 10 oi.item_id, COUNT(1) as item_count, 1 as item_type
FROM t_ord_item oi
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT oi.basket_id
    FROM t_ord_item oi
    INNER JOIN t_ord_order o ON o.ord_id = oi.ord_id
    WHERE oi.item_id = @item_id
    AND oi.status_code <> 'del'
    AND o.status_code <> 'del'
    AND o.status_code <> 'can'
    GROUP BY oi.basket_id
) as bsk ON bsk.basket_id = oi.basket_id
WHERE oi.item_id IS NOT NULL
AND oi.item_id <> @item_id
GROUP BY oi.item_id
ORDER BY item_count DESC

INSERT INTO @items (item_id, item_count, item_type)
SELECT TOP 10 oi.item_id, COUNT(1) as item_count, 2 as item_type
FROM t_ord_item oi
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT login_name_created
    FROM t_ord_item
    WHERE item_id = @item_id
    AND status_code <> 'del'
    and login_name_created is not null
    GROUP BY login_name_created
) as login ON login.login_name_created = oi.login_name_created
WHERE oi.item_id IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @items temp WHERE temp.item_id = oi.item_id)
AND oi.item_id <> @item_id
GROUP BY oi.item_id
ORDER BY item_count DESC";
```

But when I run the web app I get this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
```

I thought I was missing spaces so that I was trying to add, but still the same problem. I have published the code as before so that you can help me detect the problemstrong text

Comment: The error is from a different statement. There's no "with" or cursor anywhere in what is posted.

Comment: Hook up SQL Profiler to see what statements are actually passed to the server. If the error happens as a result of executing this statement somehow, you should find it's getting preprocessed/transformed/embedded in another query in a way that breaks it, or else there's a misbehaving trigger on a table somewhere.